# As a beginner, should I match breathing to exercise or exercise to breathing?

Tags: exercise, breathing, beginners

I started light exercises in [Ring Fit Adventure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_Fit_Adventure) to get rid of some of corona-fat and rebuild stamina lost during chain of medical stuff. Its going well however I can't match breath-in breath-out tempo in most of exercises. In most exercises I can go ~1.5 rep on my default breath, but on slow "yoga" moves I'd have to hold breath a bit to match it.

Should I put an effort in matching breath to movements, or do them slower/faster instead?

Comment: You should breathe naturally.